# Firebase User Object is null on Localhost

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine

I am having an issue with Firebase tokens on localhost.

```
@Api(name = "account",
 version = "v1",
 authenticators =  {EspAuthenticator.class},
 issuers =        {@ApiIssuer(  name = "firebase",
                                issuer =     "https://securetoken.google.com/PROJECTID",
                                jwksUri =     "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")},
 issuerAudiences = {@ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences =     {"PROJECTID"})})             
public class AccountService {

    @ApiMethod(path="user/{id}", httpMethod = "get")
    public User GetUser(@Named("id") String id, User user) throws UnauthorizedException,BadRequestException,NotFoundException    
    {
    }
}
```

In particular the User user which should return com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User. 
When I run this on google cloud then I get returned the correct result.

When I run this on localhost it always returns null.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong as Localhost should be ok with firebase by default as shown below. Why cannot I not see the user object on localhost?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to this existing question.
[Google Cloud Endpoints + Firebase Auth: method_info is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749021/google-cloud-endpoints-firebase-auth-method-info-is-not-set/55175240#55175240)

The openapi document hadn't been deployed so the user wasn't included.
Calling the following solved this issue:-

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy target/openapi-docs/openapi.json
```