# Google Cloud Endpoints - API method only called successfully when user parameter is removed

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, openapi

I have an API method (written in Java) in an application that's deployed as a set of endpoints that run on Google Cloud. The API is using OpenAPI and uses ESP ([Extensible Service Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/frameworks-extensible-service-proxy)) to relay requests from the API and mediate any authentication.

I've created a new API method which looks like the following:

```
@ApiMethod(path="my/path/{param}",httpMethod = "get")
public Object[] GetSomethingUsingFirebaseAuthentication(@Named("param") String param) throws UnauthorizedException,BadRequestException,NotFoundException
{
     // implementation
}
```

I can debug when running local by using Debug As > App Engine, and I can call the method as follows using Postman, when I'm debugging using 'debug as > app engine'. The Postman setup I'm using is as follows (note that I'm passing an authentication token in the 'bearer' of the Authorization header):

[image]

The method is successfully called and returns a success response, which proves I'm calling the method correctly and that it's valid. If I then add a parameter to accept a Firebase user like this, the method fails:

```
@ApiMethod(path="my/path/{param}",httpMethod = "get")
public Object[] GetSomethingUsingFirebaseAuthentication(@Named("param") String param, User user) throws UnauthorizedException,BadRequestException,NotFoundException
{
     // some auth code based on the Firebase 'user'
}
```

I call the method now that I've added the User parameter, exactly the same way as before using Postman, and I now get an http 503 error of:

`method_info is not set`

Here's the actually http JSON response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "backendError",
                "message": "backend error"
            }
        ],
        "code": 503,
        "message": "backend error"
    }
}
```

The issue is very similar to this one:

[Google Cloud Endpoints + Firebase Auth: method_info is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749021/google-cloud-endpoints-firebase-auth-method-info-is-not-set)

The difference with my issue though is that I still get the issue when I deploy the endpoints API to the production environment.

I have other very similar API methods that accept a Firebase user, and they're all working in production. One of the similar API methods also works when I debug it locally, so I shouldn't need a config change.

The accepted answer for the above question (modifying the mapping in web.xml to get the filter to work that's supposed to inject method_info) doesn't work for me. In any case, that would be a hack for my own issue, since the other API methods seem to be working locally and in production.

---

Some explanation of how this should work - ESP (Extensible Service Proxy), which is a Google Cloud thing, is a wrapper for the endpoint API and it can mediate the authentication using a Firebase token for the user (in my case this token gets passed in the Bearer of the Authorization header). The authenticated Firebase user should then be passed in as the `user` argument.

---

Here's the full stack trace

```
WARNING: exception occurred while invoking backend method
java.lang.IllegalStateException: method_info is not set in the request
    at com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator.authenticate(EspAuthenticator.java:67)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.Auth.authenticate(Auth.java:101)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.getUser(ServletRequestParamReader.java:205)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.deserializeParams(ServletRequestParamReader.java:141)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.RestServletRequestParamReader.read(RestServletRequestParamReader.java:135)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:349)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.dispatcher.PathDispatcher.dispatch(PathDispatcher.java:50)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at com.google.api.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:229)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.doFilter(ConfigFilter.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The only warning I get in Eclipse when I debug is

`WARNING: No file found for: /_ah/start`

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue, or what I could look at? Any advice on how I might debug or diagnose the issue is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The OpenAPI file for the endpoints API needed to be regenerated and deployed out to the *production* Google Cloud endpoints for the auth to work when debugging locally.

```
$ mvn clean package endpoints-framework:openApiDocs -DskipTests
$ gcloud endpoints services deploy target/openapi-docs/openapi.json
$ mvn appengine:run
```

The local version of the endpoints API references a production-only Firebase auth service, which in turn must be getting it's endpoint API reference from the `openapi.json` in the production endpoints API.

From the Google [OpenAPI Overview](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview):

> An OpenAPI document describes the surface of your REST API, and
>   defines information such as:
>
> The name and description of the API. The individual endpoints (paths)
>   in the API. How the callers are authenticated.